# How to add an object to nested array using indexing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux, react-redux

**This is a very simple JSON structure of what my data kind of looks like.**

I need to return the entire people array. I feel like there's a proper way to do this without creating a new list and a new info array, and splicing out the old array with the new array. I simply want to append or add the new object, to the old array.

```js
**JSON People Data** = [

{name: "n1", 
info: [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a2", phone: "p2"} ]
},

{name: "n2", 
info: [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a2", phone: "p2"} ]

]
```

**QUESTION:**

How do I add an Info object of (address & phone) to the second person array of the second info array and return the entire people array?

**IDEAL RESULT:**

```js
**JSON People Data** = [

{name: "n1", 
info: [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a2", phone: "p2"} ]
},

{name: "n2", 
info: [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a2", phone: "p2"}, {address: "a3", phone: "p3"} ]

]
```

**I FIRST TRIED:**

```html
**const newListConcat** = people[1].info.concat({address: "a3", phone: "p3"})
```

**THEN I TRIED:**

```html
**const newListPush** = people[1].info.push({address: "a3", phone: "p3"})
```

**BUT IT'S RETURNING:**

```html
// console.log  - [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a1", phone: "p1"} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected some typos, but this works as desired:

```js
const people = [
{
name: "n1", 
info: [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a2", phone: "p2"} ]
},
{
name: "n2", 
info: [ {address: "a1", phone: "p1"}, {address: "a2", phone: "p2"} ]
}
];

people[1].info.push({address: "a3", phone: "p3"});

console.log(people);
```

```html
**const newListPush** = people[1].info.push({address: "a3", phone: "p3"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are expecting. You did it right when you called `info.push()`

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: 'n1',
    info: [
      { address: 'a1', phone: 'p1' },
      { address: 'a2', phone: 'p2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'n2',
    info: [
      { address: 'a1', phone: 'p1' },
      { address: 'a2', phone: 'p2' },
    ],
  },
];

people[1].info.push({address: "a3", phone: "p3"});

console.log(JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));
```